# Dynamic content with v-show in Bootstrap vue popover

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-popover, bootstrap-vue

I am struggling to show a dynamic content inside my popover built with Bootstrap Vue component.

I want to show a form first, and when that form is submitted successfully I want to show a confirmation text instead.

I tried to manage that with v-show directive within the popover content with no success. Everything is displayed of course outside the div with the v-show directive.

The result is that it just shows an empty popover (except the close link) inside the popover.

Here is my component :

```
<template>
  <div class="email-content">
    <div class="email-content__buttons">
      <b-button variant="blue" class="fv-round" id="testEmailSend" :disabled="isPopoverDisplayed" @click="isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed = true">{{locales.testButton}}</b-button>
      <b-popover target="testEmailSend"
                 :show="isPopoverDisplayed"
                 placement="auto"
                 @show="isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed = true"
                 @shown="setFocusOnPopoverForm">
        <template>
          <b-btn @click="isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed = false" class="close">
            <span class="d-inline-block">&times;</span>
          </b-btn>
        </template>
        <div v-show="isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed">
          <b-form-group :label="`${locales.sendTo} :`" label-for="popoverEmailForm" class="mb-1" :invalid-feedback="locales.emailMandatory">
            <b-input-group>
              <b-form-input ref="emailTestReceiver" id="popoverEmailForm" :validationState="$v.emailTestReceiver" size="sm" v-model="emailTestReceiver"></b-form-input>
              <b-input-group-append>
                <b-btn @click="sendEmailTest" size="sm" :disabled="$v.$invalid" variant="primary">Ok</b-btn>
              </b-input-group-append>
            </b-input-group>
          </b-form-group>
        </div>
      </b-popover>
      <div v-show="isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed" placement="auto">
        {{locales.emailSentConfirmation}}
      </div>
      <b-button variant="primary" class="fv-round" @click="saveTemplates">{{locales.saveButton}}</b-button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';
  import { required, email } from 'vuelidate/lib/validators';
  import feedbackHandler from '@/components/_shared/Alerts/ErrorHandler';
  import SellerEmailContentConfig from '@/components/SellerDashboard/SellerEmail/SellerEmailContent/SellerEmailContentConfig';
  import locales from './sellerEmailContent.locales.json';

  export default {
    name: 'SellerEmailContent',
    data() {
      return {
        locales,
        emailTestReceiver: '',
        isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed: false,
        isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed: false
      }
    },
    validations: {
      emailTestReceiver: {
        required,
        email
      }
    },
    computed: {
      isPopoverDisplayed() {
        return this.isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed || this.isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed;
      }
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions({
        sendEmail: 'sendAuthCustomEmail'
      }),
      async sendEmailTest() {
        const { error: errorSending } = await this.sendEmail({ type: 'Seller', email: this.emailTestReceiver });
        if (!errorSending) {
          this.isPopoverEmailFormDisplayed = false;
          this.isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed = true;
          setTimeout(() => { this.isPopoverConfirmationDisplayed = false }, 3000);
        } else feedbackHandler.showError(errorSending);
      },
      setFocusOnPopoverForm() {
        this.$refs.emailTestReceiver.focus();
      }
    },
  }
</script>
```

My last was as you can see above using a computed property which combines both situation (form or confirmation to be displayed).

Any idea ? I must have missed something :)

Comment: I'm not sure that b-popover is the thing that you need. the Popover is more for `tooltip-like` element. I didn't got much your case but I would suggest that you might need a `modal` element. Or if you just wan't to show a message after submitting the form then use the `alert` element. By the way what vue-bootstrap library are you using? Is it [this](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/modal#tooltips-and-popovers) one?

Comment: Yeah it is that one indeed. I don't remember precisely how I fixed it but I founded a work around...